# I want to aggregate data each same date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to aggregate data each same date.
I wrote SQL in BigQuery.
Now there is a table like

```
id | date                  | country | code
1    2015-10-16T12:00:30     Japan     A
2    2015-10-16T12:00:30     America   C
3    2017-08-20T15:50:44     America   B
4    2016-22-56T11:32:01     China     E
5    2017-08-20T15:50:44     EU        D
```

I want to change upper tabble into this

```
id    | date                  | country       | code
1,2    2015-10-16T12:00:30     Japan,America    A,C
3,5    2017-08-20T15:50:44     America,EU       B,D
4      2016-22-56T11:32:01     China            E
```

It is like  put together id・country・code in each date.

How should I write query to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bigquery [string_agg](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators) function in standard sql.

```
select string_agg(id, ',') as id
    , string_agg(country, ',') as country
    , string_agg(code, ',') as code
from tableA
group by date
```

> Note: You need to enable first **standard sql** support. Using this
>   [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)

**Legacy SQL**, you can use `group_concat()` function. See this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#group_concat).

```
 select group_concat(id, ',') as id
        , group_concat(country, ',') as country
        , group_concat(code, ',') as code
 from tableA
 group by date
```

Comment: thank you for  your answer.I got an error like Unrecognized function string_agg [Try using standard SQL (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)] .I tried to choose legacy SQL,so I got string_agg error.How should i fix this?

Comment: thank you but I got an error,Unrecognized function format [Try using standard SQL (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)].

Comment: Why can't i do it?

Comment: @rinrin0000, yes you need to enable first standard sql support, try use group_concat